# Obtain one statistics on SingleStat of Grafana with influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I want to make one single stat on grafana with influxdb. Sample data in influxDB is:

```
> select * from log where time < now() - 2h and value1<100
name: log
---------
time                name    value1  value2  value3 
2018-04-09T01:17:55.350626995Z  h1  75  120 80
2018-04-09T01:18:37.58407287Z   h1  80  94  89
2018-04-13T03:39:38.22804839Z   h1  78  200 200
2018-04-13T03:39:38.22804839Z   h2  80  200 200
```

Here the `log` is measurement. `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are fields; while the `name` is a tag. The value for the tag name can be `h1`, `h2`, and so on.

I want to count the number of unique names, the value1 of which are less than 100. Here it should display 2 (i.e., `h1` and `h2`). So I choose the [Single Stat](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/singlestat/) plugin.

My problem is at the `Metric` tab of SingleStat. In this tab, I select the datasource, but only tag(name) is allowed to be added here, and the condition like `value1<100` is not allowed here.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Did you try to toggle the edition of query so you can input a custom query? I believe you'll be able to use the query you want.

Comment: @RebecaMaia Yes, I can do that. The issue is that the query in the custom query is overwritten after the page is refreash (i.e.., 1m here).

Comment: Well, it'll be overwritten if you don't save changes. Other than that, I don't see why it would be overwritten...